# Install Python-Dbus in virtualenv

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, dbus

I am running an application in a virtual environment that needs access to DBus (to interact with the Network Manager, mainly).

I tried to install Dbus-Python with easyinstall and pip, but both fail.

When I try to do this:

```
(myvirtualenv)borrajax@borrajax-computer:~/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnvs/current_env$ bin/pip install dbus-python
```

Pip yells at me with:

```
Downloading/unpacking dbus-python
  Downloading dbus-python-1.1.1.tar.gz (596kB): 596kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dbus-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/borrajax/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnvs/current_env/build/dbus-python/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/borrajax/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnvs/current_env/build/dbus-python/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/borrajax/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnvs/current_env/build/dbus-python
Storing complete log in /home/borrajax/.pip/pip.log
```

I have had some issues with the python dbus bindings and their "accessibility" from my Python modules in the past, so I don't really know what may be the best way to set Dbus-Python in a virtual environment. Has anyone successfully achieved this? Or does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When `pip` tries to install a package, it looks for `setup.py`, which `dbus-python` doesn't have, so you'll have to [download the source](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus-python/) and compile it manually. Shouldn't be too hard:

```
PYTHON=python3.3 ./configure --prefix=/tmp/dbus-python
make
make install
```

then you can move the compiled files to your virtualenv.

---

edit: starting with dbus-python-1.2.2 (released 2016-02-22) dbus-python has a `setup.py`, so pip should be able to install it

Answer (score 23):

Go to your Venv follow this 2 steps :

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-1-dev

pip install dbus-python
```

verify with:

```
pip freeze
```

> if installed properly you will see:     dbus-python==1.2.8

Answer (score 20):

My suggestion is to install the system package for the Python DBUS bindings and then create the *virtualenv* with the `--system-site-packages` command line option to enable access to the system-wide Python packages (including the `dbus` package) from the activated *virtualenv*. For example on Debian/Ubuntu (or a derived distribution):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dbus
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages dbus-venv
```

To use the built in Python 3 [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module instead of `virtualenv`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dbus
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
$ python3 -m venv --system-site-packages my_venv
```

Answer (score 10):

Another workaround is to just manually copy the `dbus` files/libraries directly to your virtualenv:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/pythonX.X/{site or dist}-packages/dbus myvirtenv/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/    
cp -r /usr/lib/pythonX.X/{site or dist}-packages/_dbus_*.so myvirtenv/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/
```

Comment: I like this idea as a lot of systems are going to have dbus-python due to internally used scripts and it can work well with the virtualenvwrapper `postmkvirtualenv` script.

Comment: While this solution is not exactly what I would characterized as perfectly clean, I like it for simplicity. Upvoting. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The OP appears to have opened a [ticket on freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55439) for this, which remains open; however there is a [patch attached to that ticket](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=80061) that could be applied to most any version of python-dbus and then repackaged as a new tarball.

Comment: Oh! That wasn't me. I hadn't seen that patch, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: Can confirm it's working correctly for `dbus-python==1.2.4` in virtualenv. Building it succesfully needs `sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-1-dev`

Comment: Thanks @TheMeaningfulEngineer, your comment answered this question for me.

Answer (score 3):

@TheMeaningfulEngineer thank so much, i have being having a few problem to install dbus through pip and that was what i needed i hope you have a good day wherever you are ;)

to check if there is in local - `sudo apt list --installed | grep package-name`

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-1-dev
```

and after this line I did install `dbus` and `networkmanager` without any errors

This is exactly what I did, and before that I checked out all my dbus version and networkmanager after do what @TheMeaningfulEngineer said is working.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

For Python as **dbus-python** is now obsolete, you should be using **pydbus**:

---

```
pip install pydbus
```

This have worked for me.

Comment: is it really obsolete? if you look at the release note, you'll see more recent releases than pydbus: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/news.html