# AttributeError: module 'dbus' has no attribute 'lowlevel'

Tags: python, pycharm, dbus

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/connect4.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_dbus_bindings/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import dbus.lowlevel as __dbus_lowlevel
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/lowlevel.py", line 32, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_dbus_bindings/ErrorMessage.py", line 13, in <module>
    import dbus.lowlevel as __dbus_lowlevel
AttributeError: module 'dbus' has no attribute 'lowlevel'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are the **dbus** files mentioned in the error path:

[image]

and the **dbus_bindings** files:

[image]

What is missing? How to solve this issue?

I've already reinstalled the packages using

```
sudo apt install  python3-dbus
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dbus
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue might be that you are using a venv. `python3-dbus` does not play nicely with venv's.

You can try using `--system-site-packages` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367493/7721752.

Or use [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) and [vext.gi](https://pypi.org/project/vext.gi/)